# How to change all the fonts correctly?

Tags: fonts, xetex

I am very new to LaTeX. I'm learning it basically to write texts which are very heavy on mathematics. Also I am not an English speaker (my language is not too crazy, it just has a few letters with accents).

After doing some research I ended up with XeLaTeX using *fontspec* and *polyglossia*.
Everything is fine, however default fonts look awkward, namely some letter parts look too thin when printed. Since I am not a font-fashion guru I'd love to know some popular alternatives and how to implement them correctly...

Here is my clumsy preamble at the moment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{lithuanian} %Do I need this?
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=2.5cm, outer=1.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%Fancyhdr settings here
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

I looked around and found out that some people like *Palatino* font and *mathpazo* which may be somewhat matching (text and math wise). As a result I tried adding:

```
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}
```

Above seems to work at a first glance, but I'm worried that I'll run into some problems later on (now my texts are very basic). What do you think about that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) No need to add thanks, simply upvote any good answer to your question to reward the reply.

Comment: not addressing your main question, but a comment on your list of packages:  `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, and `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`, so only the first of each pair is needed.

Comment: If you write in Lithuanian, then you definitely need to set the language (with `\setmainlanguage`). The loading order of the font packages seems OK. You might want to try `\usepackage{unicode-math}` and the "TG Pagella Math" font.

Comment: I like the Fourier-GUTen­berg repackaging of Adobe's Utopia (`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage{fourier}`). Looks nice, quite compact. I mostly write in Spanish (also mostly roman letters with some accents thrown in, plus I've got some names with exotic accents in my bibliographies).